# Missing NFC tag protocol in profiles issue in iOS 13 and Xcode 11

Tags: ios, ios13, xcode11, swift5

Provisioning profiles showing error after adding **NFC tag-specific data protocol** to entitlements which is requirement of iOS 13 and Xcode 11 for using NFC in app.

I have re-checked the profiles NFC is enabled for the bundle-id and provisioning profiles are also valid and includes NFC.

I need to upload a production build but because of this error I am not able to. Is this iOS 13 or Xcode 11 bug? What should I do for fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a number of hit and trials, I was able to solve this issue.
Here are steps I followed:

1) In developer site, Open your app identifier, click edit, disable NFC and then re enable it.

2) Re-download the provisioning profiles and install them.

Reason behind it could be when we re-download the profiles it contained information about new NFC tag item which solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Preeti. I have the same issue here. I started with an app that uses NFC and is built with Xcode 10.2

It is my aim to update this app to build using Xcode 11.1 However when I do so I get an error saying that have missing entitlements, I can solve this error by adding TAG to my entitlements file like this:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
    <array>
        <string>NDEF</string>
        <string>TAG</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

However once you do this this is where I encounter the issue you describe, my build now complains that my provisioning profile "doesn't match the entitlements file value for the com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats entitlement." Is this the same issue you are having?

This despite my profiles having previously contained the NFC tagging entitlement, and having worked fine on Xcode 10.2 Have these entitlements changed for Xcode 11 and how do we solve this and maintain backward compatibility?

Comment: Yes Chris S, I am facing exactly same issue.

Comment: did you get this sorted?

Comment: Not currently no, however my profiles are due to expire in January so I have pushed this work back until then.  I plan on re-generating all of my provisioning profiles. I believe once I do this they will contain both the NDEEF and TAG entitlements so hopefully it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using >iOS13.0: [This link gave the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61265904) (i.e eliminate the NDEF-entry in your entitlement)